# Truncated input when piping to another command in Bash in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

I used to be able to handle piping just fine, but recently I’ve been having problems with Bash truncating output when it’s piped into another command. What could be causing this?

I'm using Bash on Mac OS X 10.11.1.

The command I’m using, in this example is leveraging the Microsoft Azure Cross-Platform (xPlat) CLI Tool, which runs on top of Node.js:

```
azure provider list --json | pbcopy
```

## Actual Pipeline Output Received

Commands such as `jsawk` or `pbcopy` are only actually seeing this:

```
jsawk: JSON parse error: '[
  {
    "resourceTypes": [
      {
        "apiVersions": [
          "2015-10-31",
          "2015-01-01-preview"
        ],
        "locations": [
          "Japan East",
          "East US 2",
          "West Europe",
          "Southeast Asia",
          "South Central US"
        ],
        "properties": {},
        "name": "automationAccounts"
      },
      {
        "apiVersions": [
          "2015-10-31",
          "2015-01-01-preview"
        ],
        "locations": [
          "Japan East",'
```

Comment: What happens when you run `azure provider list --json | less` -- does your data get truncated?

Comment: @glennjackman: Yes, it is truncated that way as well. It seems to only be a problem with piping, because it emits full output when I don't pipe at all. The full output is emitted to stdout. I also tried using zsh, so it doesn't seem to be a problem with Bash itself.

Comment: Maybe can be useful to have the full output to reply your problem. If I correctly understand what you posted is what it survived. If so the next character(s) should be the interesting one(s). Redirect the output to a file and see if the problem persists and if not if persists in the file if it reappears doing `less outfile`...

Comment: unless part of the output goes to stderr. Try `azure ... 2>&1 | less`

Comment: I tried the `2>&1 | less` redirection, and it's still truncated there.